# How to take input from user until a specific character appears

Tags: bash, text

How can I read from standard input until a specific character appears like in the example:

```bsh
while [[ input is not $ ]]; do
    read -p ...
    for ...
done
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe why you're doing this (there may be a better way), and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `read` with `$` as a delimiter. `read` will stop reading from the standard input as soon as it encounters the delimiter. For this, you don't really need a loop.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

read -d $ -p 'input characters: '
[[ $? = 0 ]] && \
printf 'Jackpot! You typed: %s\n' $
```

On the other hand, if you want to check characters before printed to the screen, then you can use the parameter `-N` to instruct `read` to interrupt after reading one character, where you can break before anything printed.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

echo -n 'input characters: '
while read -N 1 -s -r; do
    [[ $REPLY = $ ]] && \
    { printf '\njackpot! you typed: %s\n' $; break; } || printf %s "$REPLY"
done
```